# Font is different on random devices

Tags: android, fonts

I'm using *Montserrat-Bold.otf* font in my app which is in Thai. There are some devices on what the characters are visible partly. I mean the top of some characters are not visible (like cut). See in the pics.

[image: Normal View][image: Example of non normal view]

Also Java code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv)).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "Montserrat-Bold.otf"));
    }
```

And XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hayk.temp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="รายการนี้ถูกแลกแล้ว"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S. I would like to mention that when I open web page with Thai words with the same font, I don't have this kind of problem.

Comment: You need to add more information here - which version of Android are you seeing this for, which SDK are you using to build your app, etc. Both of those greatly determine which features you can make use of, and you should certainly look up whether the features you're trying to make use of (in this case, `otf` flavoured OpenType fonts) are supported by the platforms you're targetting, and the SDK you're using to compile your code.

Comment: Android version is 4.4.4 , Samsung Galaxy S4 
compileSdkVersion 23

You mean if I'll test app on another device with android version 4.4.4 I'll meet this problem too?

Comment: that would seem quite likely. 4.* still has incompletions when it comes to `otf` support, so depending on how "proper" this font is, it might cause problems on any device running Android 4.*

Answer (score 0):

**Android does not support OpenType(.otf).**

**Use a TrueType(.ttf) font.**

Apparently OpenType is now supported to some devices. but It was not supported originally, so you will want use any font better way is use .ttf

Comment: This is plain not true? Modern Android supports `otf` just fine (and even v2.1 and up support most otf). Also, you're using a massive misnomers here: both ttf and otf are OpenType fonts; you can be imprecise in a tweet, but not in an SO answer. Old versions of Android do not support OpenType fonts with CFF data (`otf`) natively, and only support OpenType fonts with TrueType outlines (`ttf`). New versions of Android support both perfectly fine.